# How to "bind" invisible and unbound field in ASPXGridView EditFromTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView with edit form template. DataSource for this grid is EntityServerModeSource which is a read-only data source. I use this combination because it delegates filtering and sorting to database server.

For simplicity I will present simplified scenario.
My EntityServerModeSource return rows with fields A,B and C.

What I do for update is following. In EditFormTemplate I have controls which I bind to fields A and B. Something like:

```
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("A")%>' />
<asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("B")%>' />
```

For update I have a stored procedure which expects 3 parameters A, B and C. In RowUpdating of ASPxGridView event I check for e.NewValues collection. The problem is that it only contains fields A and B and not C. This is expected and normal because field C was not bound to any control. E.g. NewValues["C"] returns null. But I need the old value of C so I can pass it to stored procedure which expects all three. I cannot just make up a some value because this would overwrite existing value in database.

My hacky solution was to make a dummy control inside EditFormTemplate, bind it to field C and make it invisible like so:

```
<div style="display: none">
    <asp:TextBox Text= '<%# Bind("C")%>' />
</div>
```

Now, the field C is bound and in RowUpdating event I can access it with e.OldValue["C"].
But this is a hacky solution and I dont like it. Is there a way to "bind" field C in code-behind or in some way to force field C to appear in OldVaues and NewValues collections?

Answer (score 0):

For getting values which are not bound to a UI element use the [ASPxGridView.GetRowValues](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_GetRowValuestopic) method. Pass the `FocusedRowIndex` and the column name of the column, then cast it to your desired type.

```
string C = ASPxGridView.GetRowValues(ASPxGridView.FocusedRowIndex, "C") as string;
```